# Does "extends" also extend variables?

Tags: java, drawing, hierarchy, extends

I figured when you extend an object from another object, that object then receives all of the variables and the definition of those variables as well as that objects methods. So when I have code like this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public abstract class Object extends JComponent{
    private int xpos;
    private int ypos;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private double rotate;
    private Rectangle rect;

    public Object(int p1, int p2, int w, int h, double r){
        this.xpos = p1;
        this.ypos = p2;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.rotate = r;
        rect = new Rectangle(xpos, ypos, width, height);
    }
}
```

as the original object, and then another object like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Block extends Object{

    public Block(int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4, double r) {
        super(p1, p2, p3, p4, r);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D gd = (Graphics2D) g;
        gd.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        gd.draw(rect);
    }

}
```

Why isn't the rectangle "rect" being extended over? I am sorta new at java and still learning so please go easy on me XD

Comment: _Why isn't the rectangle "rect" being extended over?_ where do you expect it to be ?

Comment: Why do you redefine `Object` class? Are you aware of the multiple problems this would give?

Comment: why? is there already an Object class? if there is I didn't know about it

Comment: I expected "rect" to be extended over because I thought thats how extension works. All variables & methods of the upper class get extended to the lower class.

Comment: Read [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), specifially the part where it says: **Private Members in a Superclass**

A subclass does not inherit the private members of its parent class. However, if the superclass has public or protected methods for accessing its private fields, these can also be used by the subclass.

Comment: *is there already an Object class? if there is I didn't know about it* I highly recommend you to stop doing this and learn Java. `Object` is the base class for all classes in Java, and is covered in basic lessons.

Answer (score 3):

`rect` is marked as private in `Object`.  So it is only visible to instances of your `Object` class.  Even child classes cannot see it in their implementation.  You can do two things:

1) Create a getter method for it in `Object`.  This method is public, so any other class, including your `Block` class, can see it.

```
public Rectangle getMyRect() {
    return rect;
}
```

2) Or mark it as protected or default (no access modifier).

```
protected Rectangle rect;  // this way...
Rectangle rect;  // ... or this way
```

P.S.  Do not name classes `Object`.  It will work if the class is defined in a different package, but the class `Object` has a special meaning -- the top-most parent class of all classes -- and will confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a class, there is access to the public and protected methods and variables.  Right now, rect is a private variable.  To make it free for extended objects, simply make it protected or provide a getRect() method to allow access.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually extended but not accessible as your variable rect is defined as **private**. To be accessible in sub-classes rect should be **protected**.

Or you can also create getter and setter methods for rect.

Answer (score 0):

Learn more about access specifiers. Private member variables are only accessible within the class. hence even if you have a class that extends Rect, it will still be visible only in Object. Also do not use the class name 'Object'. It is the super class from which all other classes exten

Answer (score 0):

Extend and access are two different things....

In your case, super class private variables are not accessible. You can extend the features of super class but accessing methods and variables depend on super classes access modifiers.

Answer (score -1):

the variable "rect" won't be extended over. "extends" means you are making that class as a parent class. So the block class will inherit all the functionality the parent class contains.  So block will get all methods and you can override methods as well. Since rect is a private variable that will not be seen by the block class unless you make it public. Extends basically allows the class to inherit attributes, methods and properties of the parent class but not private variables. Hope that helps.